# Make p appear on div hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this CSS & HTML so far:

```css
.divi:hover {
  background: #01ba7c;
}
.divi:hover > p {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: relative; left: 300px;       top: 100px; border: 2px solid black;" class="divi">
  <p style="visibility:    hidden;">This is a test and better work!</p>
</div>
```

What I want is for the text to only show up when someone is hovering the div that the p is contained in. Why is this not working? All that happens is my div's background changes to the color I specified.
Thanks!

Comment: Inline styles has more specificity ... it can't be replaced by the one on the CSS file without !important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a matter of selector specifity where your inline style are stronger than any of your stylesheet rules.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2

```css
.divi {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.divi:hover {
  background: #01ba7c;
}
.divi p {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.divi:hover > p {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="divi">
  <p>This is a test and better work!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh yes i forgot about the precedence rules. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The inline style overrides the style sheet.

Change the `<p style="visibility:    hidden;">` to `<p>`

```css
.divi:hover {
background: #01ba7c;
  
}
.divi > p{
  visibility:    hidden;
}
.divi:hover > p {
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: relative; left: 300px;       top: 100px; border: 2px solid black;" class="divi">
  <p>This is a test and better work!</p>
</div>
```